# posix shared memory creation in thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, shared-memory

I am new to to Linux programming, so please be gentle!
.[image: scenario description]

I am trying to implement the above scenario. Here two process are created using `fork()` each with N number of threads.
Threads from process 1 create a request and enqueue it on the queue 1. Threads from process 2 dequeue a request and send a response back on queue 2. 
Each request consists of `shmid` and `size` where `shmid` is a shared memory segment generated like this -

```
shmid = shm_open(<a random string>, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);

if (shmid < 0) {
    perror("failure on shm_open");
    exit(1);
}
if (ftruncate(*share, size) == -1) {
    perror("Error on ftruncate\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

I am able to open and modify this shared memory segment immediately in the same thread after creation using

```
void* request = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shmid, 0);
memset(str, 'w', size);
```

After this I pass on the shmid to process 2 using queue 1.

My problem is when the threads in process 2 try to open this shmid using the same way, I get a `EBADF: fd is not a valid file descriptor` error. I have verified that the shmid is correct after dequeuing by printing the value in both process 1 and 2.

Is creating shared memory segments between processes not possible when they are created from a different process/thread? Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Why not use message queues instead?

Comment: Unix message queues instead of the queue? I will probably switch to that in the future. But will that help with my current problem? I didn't think they are related...

Comment: Posix message queues, yes. https://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview or Unix local datagram sockets like someone else suggested. Why make life difficult by reinventing the wheel? Use existing message passing functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shared memory segment must be opened in both processes.

If both processes are created by `fork()` from a common parent, then you can just do the `shm_open()` prior to the `fork()`, and it will be inherited by both child processes.

Alternatively, each process can call `shm_open()`, passing the same value for the `name` parameter.

Comment: The alternate solution is what I was looking for! My requests have variable size, so I don't know the size to allocate pre-`fork()`. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. when opening the shared memory for the second time, open it without the `O_TRUNC` flag set. `O_TRUNC` truncates the shared memory object to 0 bytes. source - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to access a file descriptor made by another process, it will not work. File descriptors are only good in the process they were created in. Im only saying this because of the error you are seeing.

But you have the right idea for sharing memory, you can either make a shared segment of mapped memory to both processes, which may get hairy with race conditions with multiple threads in each process competing to access it, or you could create a socket, and have your two processes communicate through that, or a pipe.

I would recommend an AF_UNIX socket for IPC like you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes I will have to switch to sockets if using the queue doesn't pan out. The only reason I implemented the queue was because it was stated in my requirements...

Comment: I was thinking that you could possibly put a mutex at the head of the mapped piece of memory, then the threads from two processes could lock and unlock. Just an idea.

Comment: Yes I am already doing that. I have mapped a posix mutex and a condition variable to shared memory and am using that for synchronization.